# How to solve convert data type error in C# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I try to do statistics for my excel data, but I have an error at this line in my code

```
ProGroup.Sum(r => r.Field<string>("Time"))
```

Time is string format in my excel data but eclipse doesn't accept that and shows me an error message

```
Can't implicitly convert type "string" to "long"
```

How I can correct it please? I tried

`Convert.ToDecimal(ProGroup.Sum(r => r.Field<string>("Timmar")))`

but it show me an error too.

```
 var data = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
            group r by r.Field<string>("Project") into ProGroup
            let SumTime = ProGroup.Sum(r => r.Field<string>("Time"))
            select new
            {
                Projekt = ProGroup.Key,
                Sum = SumTime
            };
```

Comment: So how do you want to calculate and sum an string column? Check the reference to see the valid parameters for `Sum`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I'm a new in linq, I don't know how to sum total hours for every project

Comment: Did you try `ProGroup.Sum(r => r.Field<long>("Time"))`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with LINQ. You can't sum strings. You'll have to parse the string into a value that can be summed, like int, double, TimeSpan. What does that field contain? A number? Time in `HH:MM` form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert every item

```
...
let SumTime = ProGroup.Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Field<string>("Time")))
...
```

P.S. You need to be sure all the time values are in correct format.